# How to list tables of specific database and sort them by size with PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql

I have tried to select a list of databases and select all tables from each database, ordering the first ten tables by their size - including their indexes- through PL/pgSQL, but I have had a problem to join the query for the database with the query for the tables and their sizes included in the specific database.

I have started like this:

```
    DO $$
DECLARE
  database_name pg_database.datname%TYPE;
  total_table_size pg_tables.tablename%TYPE;
    rec record;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT datname
  FROM pg_database
LOOP
  database_name := rec.datname;
 
  raise notice 'Database name: %', database_name;
 
  SELECT tablename,
  pg_total_relation_size(table_name) AS total_table_size
  FROM pg_tables
  INTO table_name, total_table_size
  ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(relid) DESC
  LIMIT 10;
 END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

I do not know how to specify that I want the first ten table names and their sizes ordered from the largest to the smallest of the present selected database. Could anyone help me with it, please?

I thought about joining the queries somehow, but I have not found a column that I could use to make the join.

I have searched similar problems in the community, but I did not find something so specific.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're already limiting the result to just top 10 rows through the addition of [`LIMIT 10`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html#QUERIES-LIMIT). You're just duplicating the same 10 rows as many times as there are databases in your catalog, but still those are results for the current database you're connected to.
2. You're probably familiar with all [Database Object Size Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) but while it's good to order by the raw byte size, run it through `pg_size_pretty()` in your select section to make it readable.
3. Don't forget about [schemas/namespaces](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createschema.html). You can have multiple of those in a single database, and a table of the same name in each one. In `pg_tables` it's under `schemaname`, in `information_schema.tables` it's under `table_schema`. [The recommendation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/views.html) is

   > Since the information schema is SQL-standard whereas the views described here are PostgreSQL-specific, it's usually better to use the information schema if it provides all the information you need.
4. While you can list all databases, roles and tablespaces available on the cluster in system catalogs, there's no cluster-wide catalog for namespaces and tables. There's no native/built-in/standard way in PostgreSQL to switch databases from inside the session, nor is there a way to reference objects in other databases, be it on the same cluster or elsewhere. To be able to do these things from within your session, you need [`postgres_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) or [`dblink`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-function.html) both of which actually start and additional client on your behalf.

   Off-db, you can simply instruct your client to open and close connections wherever and however you want (the idea with [`\c` or `\connect -reuse-previous=on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-C-LC) in `psql`) as long as you're fine shoveling the data yourself and having to maintain a separate utility.
5. There are pre-built [external tools](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Monitoring) you can use to monitor PostgreSQL.
6. `CREATE VIEW v_pg_total_relation_sizes` on each of your databases ([here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage) are examples you can just prepend with `create view ... as`). To make it present by default in databases created in the future, create one in [`template1` database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html) as well. Make them visible through `postgres_fdw`, then create a view that's a `union` of the local one and all the linked ones. Depending on how large your databases are, if this gets slow you might want to consider making it a [`materialized view`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html) to cache it.

Here's a demo for point 6 above: [(db<>fiddle)](https://dbfiddle.uk/TEIwUlSK)

```
create table local_table as
select generate_series(1,2e5,1), (gen_random_uuid())::text;

create view v_pg_total_relation_sizes as 
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation",
    pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "readable_size",
    pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) as size
FROM pg_class C
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema', 'pg_toast')
ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) DESC;
```

Connect to your [`template1`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html) database (it's always created during initial PostgreSQL setup since it's meant to be just that: a template for all new databases) and create similar objects:

```
create schema neighbour_schema;

create table neighbour_schema.neighbour_table as
select generate_series(1,3e5,1), (gen_random_uuid())::text;

create view neighbour_schema.v_pg_total_relation_sizes as 
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation",
    pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "readable_size",
    pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) as size
  FROM pg_class C
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
  WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema', 'pg_toast')
  ORDER BY pg_total_relation_size(C.oid) DESC;

create database neighbour_db;
```

Now that they are in `template1`, all new databases created with `create database` will have it from the start.

When setting up `postgres_fdw` (and/or `dblink`), note that by default it'll use [local Unix domain socket](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING-URIS) if you don't supply host and user information. For different users and hosts make sure you're also keeping [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) up to date on all instances you connect/link to.

On your main db:

```
create extension postgres_fdw;

CREATE SERVER foreign_server
        FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
        OPTIONS (dbname 'neighbour_db');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR current_user
        SERVER foreign_server
        OPTIONS (user 'postgres');
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE fdw_v_pg_total_relation_sizes (
        relation text,
        readable_size text,
        size bigint )
  SERVER foreign_server
  OPTIONS (schema_name 'neighbour_schema', 
           table_name 'v_pg_total_relation_sizes');
```

Set up the materialized view and `UNION ALL` the local and linked views:

```
create materialized view f_v_cluster_pg_total_relation_sizes as 
select current_database() as dbname,* from v_pg_total_relation_sizes
union all
select 'neighbour_db',* from fdw_v_pg_total_relation_sizes
order by size desc;

refresh materialized view f_v_cluster_pg_total_relation_sizes;

select * from f_v_cluster_pg_total_relation_sizes;
```

| dbname | relation | readable_size | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| neighbour_db | neighbour_schema.neighbour_table | 22 MB | 23076864 |
| postgres | public.local_table | 15 MB | 15736832 |
| postgres | public.f_v_cluster_pg_total_relation_sizes | 16 kB | 16384 |
| postgres | public.pg_temp_16464 | 8192 bytes | 8192 |
| postgres | public.dblink_pkey_results | 0 bytes | 0 |
| postgres | public.fdw_v_pg_total_relation_sizes | 0 bytes | 0 |
| postgres | public.v_pg_total_relation_sizes | 0 bytes | 0 |
| neighbour_db | neighbour_schema.v_pg_total_relation_sizes | 0 bytes | 0 |

Note that this view needs to be redefined whenever new databases are added, which can be automated through [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in a PL/pgSQL routine, although not fully since neither a regular trigger on `pg_databse` can be created, nor an [event trigger on `ddl_statement_start`/`_end`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-trigger-definition.html) can fire on a `create database`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have started trying it. As you said, I had already solved the point 1, and I have correct the points 2 and three. But can I ask... So do you mean I can use either dblink or postgres_fdw to be able to make the databases communicate, or I have to use both anyway? And what do you mean by "Make them visible through postgres_fdw", do you have any example? Thank you.

Comment: Not both `dblink` *and* `postgres_fdw`, only one of these. If you need recommendation, I'd pick `postgres_fdw`. There's [an example in the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html#POSTGRES-FDW-EXAMPLES). Even though you're working with views, you still link them with `create foreign` **`table`** `the_linked_thing`. Once that's done, you can conveniently `select * from the_linked_thing;` on the db you're currently connected to, even though the object is somewhere else.

Comment: I ended up confounding myself and not paying attention to a detail. This should be done using databases located in one instance. So instead of connecting databases through a dblink or postgres_fdw, I would just need to maybe add a "\c 'datname'" to my PL/pgSQL code for each found database and then make the select for the objects.

Comment: By the way, do you know what kind of data type I could use to return the pg_relation_size or total_pg_relation_size? I am getting an error when I try to select it into an oid variable through PL/pgSQL.

Comment: **1)** `\c` is a `psql` meta-command that doesn't have a plain SQL or PL/pgSQL equivalent. It's of course totally viable solution to set up an external utility that does all this (a deamon/background service connecting through `psql`), but that's a bit out of scope of the question in this thread. Plus, there'd be little difference between that and the above - both `dblink` and `postgres_fdw` use an external client, but they let you use it from within your database, in a declarative manner, without having to maintain a separate, standalone thing.

Comment: [**2)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77228730/how-to-list-tables-of-specific-database-and-sort-them-by-size-with-postgresql/77229407?noredirect=1#comment136163516_77229407) You can check that in [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE): `pg_total_relation_size ( regclass ) → bigint` - they both return `bigint`, so it's best to accept their output into a column of their native type.

Comment: Clarifying **1)** further: there's no native/built-in/standard way in PostgreSQL to switch databases from inside the session, nor is there a way to reference objects in other databases (except for cluster-level catalogs), be it on the same cluster or elsewhere. If there was, it would be trivial to simply instruct the query to fetch records from the neighbour/remote instead of the local db, or at least to collect records from within a loop, switching the target db between iterations. That's where `postgres_fdw` and `dblink` come in, and enabling that is exactly their main purpose.

Comment: I understand what you mean , thank you very much, and I apologize, in case I have expressed myself badly. I have discovered I cannot use postgres_fdw, I do not have the package I need to use it, so I would need to use a dblink. I will probably have to ask another question. I would like to create a function that would take the information I need about the objects from each database in the cluster. I have already managed to do it in the current database, but I am not really sure how to gather that info from other databases, but I have understood I will need a dblink for that.

Comment: You can share a link to the next question here, I'll take a look. In [the demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/TEIwUlSK) you can see an example using `dblink` if that helps. There's also a [`dblink_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-connect.html#id-1.11.7.22.5.9), which you could use pretty much the same way as `postgres_fdw`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to 1 database I am not sure you can get information from another database.  Possibly it could be done with a dblink.

Below will give a list of table sizes within the current database

```
    SELECT
  schema_name,
  relname,
  pg_size_pretty(table_size) AS size,
  table_size
FROM (
       SELECT
         pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname           AS schema_name,
         relname,
         pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) AS table_size
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_class
         JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON relnamespace = pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid
     ) t
WHERE schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
ORDER BY table_size DESC;
```